# ASP.NET Service alive across different pages

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a strange architecture issue. I'm creating an ASP.NET site, and very simply this site will call a webservice , that I also need to develope. This webservice opens a session to an old legacy system, and then the site has to execute functions through that webservice.

The problem is that when the webservice opens the session in the legacy system I should keep it open for as long as the session is open on my ASP.NET site. I cannot create the session and destroy it for each webservice call, I should reuse it.

Any help on this architecture will be greatly appreciated.
This is the flow, and how it should work:

http://picpaste.com/Capture-H5YbVaxF.JPG

thank you!
Victor

Comment: Any sort of code or visualization of what you're trying to do would be helpful in getting a suitable answer for your question.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the image upload. I can't link to it for you. Please use imgur if you can.